# How to pass the value to controller's method from ajax in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I am developing MVC application. 
I am trying to send value to controller method via ajax.

I have written the blow method in the view. but its simple not work.
Alert works, it shows the selected value, but rest of the part disnt work.

```
$("#btnForword").click(function(){
            d = $('#HODList').val()
            alert(d);

            var url2 = "@Html.Raw(Url.Action("SendPaymentAdviceForApproval", "PaymentAdvice", new { paymentAdviceId = "idValue" , nHOD = "D" }))";
            url2 = url2.replace("idValue",'@Model.Id');
            url2 = url2.replace("D",d);


            $.ajax({
                url: url2, type: "POST", success: function (data) {
                                      DispalyApprovalFlow();
                }
            });
            return false;
        });
```

Comment: why you dont use [`$.ajax data`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) property to pass parameter?

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this, Suppose you are calling the method *SendPaymentAdviceForApproval*.

```
$("#btnForword").click(function(){
        d = $('#HODList').val()
        alert(d);
        $.ajax({
            url:  '@Url.Action("SendPaymentAdviceForApproval", "ControllerName")',
            data: { paymentAdviceId: @Model.Id , nHOD : "D" },
        });
    }).success(function (data) {
               alert(data);
            });
```